# Does the Descartes number $D = 198585576189$ have a friend?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(X)$ be the sum of the divisors of $X$, and denote the *abundancy index* $\sigma(X)/X$ by $I(X)$.  If the equation $I(X) = r/s$ has no solution $X \in \mathbb{N}$, then $r/s$ is said to be an *[abundancy outlaw](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL10/Holdener/holdener7.pdf)*.

A number $Y \neq X$ is said to be a friend of $X$ if $I(Y) = I(X)$.  If a number $Z$ does not have a friend, then it is said to be *solitary*.  Greening's Theorem provides a sufficient but not necessary condition for a number to be solitary - namely, $\gcd\left(Z, \sigma(Z)\right) = 1 \implies Z$ is solitary.

Here is my first question:

> **(1-A)** Does the [Descartes number](http://faculty.missouri.edu/~bankswd/papers/2008_Descartes_Final.pdf) $D = 198585576189$ have a friend?

Greening's Theorem fails to establish the number's solitude, because
$$\gcd\left(D, \sigma(D)\right) = \gcd(198585576189, 426027470778) = \gcd\left({3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2}\cdot{{19}^2}\cdot{61},{2}\cdot{3^3}\cdot{7}\cdot{13}\cdot{{19}^2}\cdot{31}\cdot{61}\cdot{127}\right) = {3^2}\cdot{7}\cdot{13}\cdot{{19}^2}\cdot{61} = 18035199.$$

Here is a way to rephrase my first question:

> **(1-B)** Is there a number $\overline{D} \neq 198585576189$ such that
>   $$I(\overline{D}) = I(D) = \dfrac{{2}\cdot{3}\cdot{31}\cdot{127}}{{7}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{13}} = \dfrac{23622}{11011}?$$

Notice that $11011$ is a [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number) (in base-$10$).  Note also that $23622$ is almost a palindrome (again, in base-$10$).

This brings me to my second question:

> **(2)** Is the ratio $22622/11011$ an abundancy index or outlaw?

Comment: why do you think that the question have a  nice solution ? as we all know that "Does 10 has a friend?" is an open question.